# Tetris in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm designing a 3D Tetris game. I'm new to unity and just started to learn some basics in [this site](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/2010/09/beginner-b22-pausing-scripts-with-waitforseconds/)

My plan is not to create a regular tetris board, but to create a 3D surface, with width,height and depth so the user will need to build a surface in order to destroy the objects.

So in my design I know that I need an object generator and to create an object (Tetris cube) in they that I'm calling the object generator in the update method with some timer. 
Also the idea is to make a 3d matrix that represent the game board so I could check in the game logic if there is a "surface" in that matrix.
This is a part of the game logic script.. and my problem is that i don't know where to put this script.. I mean in the game logic I need to create a random cube, and to check if there is a surface that can be destroyed.. but where should I put the game logic script?

I always used IDE's like visual studio or eclipse so there you can have a main class with the main method that start your program.. and now in unity i'm confused..

Edit:

Thanks for your replying.. I forgot to mention that I have something like 3 scenes (levels) in the game.. so for each level (scene) should I create an empty game object?

Comment: Overall I think that may depend on how you plan on using scenes in your game, but one way I find myself doing this is creating an Empty Game object giving it an appropriate name eg: "Game Controller" and attaching my game logic script to that object... I also find myself passing references down the chain to any object that might need access to properties or methods that belong to my "Game"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an empty gameobject and attach your object that you want to spawn(as child) to it and attach your spawn code to that empty object(parent)

Comment: when you made your spawner gameobject you should save it as prefab then you can add it in each scene

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty gameobject like mentioned and put a script on it that saves it from being destroyed on scene-change (some sort of singleton).

Some basic way to do it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static GameController instance

    public static GameController Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(instance);
    }
}
```

The DontDestroyOnLoad will hold the whole gameobject with everything attached to stay loaded on scene-change.